# Pandas interpolate - don't just repeat last values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe `df` that looks like:

```
      HOUR  VALUE
0     1     2
1     2     4
2     3     6
3     4     None
4     5     None
5     6     None
```

when I do `df.interpolate(axis=0)`, it returns:

```
      HOUR  VALUE
0     1     2
1     2     4
2     3     6
3     4     6
4     5     6
5     6     6
```

Is there something I can do to return:

```
      HOUR  VALUE
0     1     2
1     2     4
2     3     6
3     4     8
4     5     10
5     6     12
```

?
I am using dummy numbers in this example, but with my real numbers, I just want to get roughly numbers that follow a linear trend, is there something that will generate numbers that follow a linear trend, and I can maybe specify things like standard dev?

Comment: may be a linear fit on `VALUE` against `HOUR`?

Comment: Is that a pandas function besides `interpolate`?

Comment: No, I think you would need to resolve to others, e.g. `np.polyfit`.

Comment: You want to `extrapolate`. Interpolation is used to fill values `between` non-null values. This requires curve fitting.